# Validation not working for radio buttons - React Hook Form, Zod

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hook-form, zod

I have a form component that uses React-Hook-Forms and Zod for validation. The validation is working just fine for all input components except radio buttons.For instance, if I have two options, and the user checks one option, zod throws an error for the option that isn't checked.

The radio buttons are nested in one parent div and there's one error message container for both options. Zod, however, doesn't seem to be aware that if one option has been checked, it shouldn't throw an error.

**form component:**

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
 {/* other fields ... */}
        <div>
          <p>Receive PIN through</p>
          <label htmlFor="receive-pin-sms">
            <input
              type="radio"
              value="SMS"
              id="receive-pin-sms"
              {...register("smsOrCall")}
              name="radio"
            />
            SMS
          </label>
          <label htmlFor="receive-pin-call">
            <input
              type="radio"
              value="Call"
              id="receive-pin-call"
              {...register("smsOrCall")}
              name="radio"
            />
            Call
          </label>
          {errors.state?.message && (
            <p>{errors.state.message}</p>
          )}
        </div>
        <div>
          <button
            type="submit"
          >
            Next Step
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
```

**validation schema:**

```
const FormSchema = z.object({
  // ...
  smsOrCall: z
    .string()
    .min(1, { message: "Please select a value" })
    .max(260, { message: "The name is too long" }),
});
```

**RHF useForm:**

```
const BusinessInformationForm: React.FC<BusinessInformationFormProps> = () => {
  const {
    register,
    formState: { errors },
    watch,
    handleSubmit,
    setValue,
  } = useForm<BusinessInformationFormInput>({
    resolver: zodResolver(FormSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      // ...
      smsOrCall: "SMS",
    },
  });
```

I'm persisting the form values to localStorage like so:

```
  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    useFormPersist("businessInformationData", {
      watch,
      setValue,
      storage: window.localStorage,
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
{errors.state?.message && (
<p>{errors.state.message}</p>
)}
```

to

```
{errors.smsOrCall?.message && (
<p className="pl-5 text-red-700 mt-1">{errors.smsOrCall.message}</p>
)}
```